# RuntimeError: Expected writable numpy.ndarray with shape set

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, face-recognition, dlib

I try to load some images into an RDD and use the face recognition library(https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) to compare different images. Following code work

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from pyspark import SparkContext


sc = SparkContext(appName="LoadingImage")
images = sc.binaryFiles("./images/")
image_to_array = lambda rawdata: np.asarray(Image.open(BytesIO(rawdata)))
i_arr = images.values().map(image_to_array)    
new_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(i_arr.first())
next_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(i_arr.first())
result = face_recognition.compare_faces([new_encoding[0]], next_encoding[0])
print(result)
```

However, when I try to map face_encodings function to all the elements inside the RDD, it always gives me an error:

> RuntimeError: Expected writable numpy.ndarray with shape set.

```
img_to_encodings = lambda img: face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
i_arrm = i_arr.map(img_to_encodings)
result = face_recognition.compare_faces([i_arrm.first()], i_arrm.first())
print(result)
```

The error is from dlib library, but I reckon I did something wrong with spark. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The frame returned by picamera has flag set to false i.e Writable : False. 
Set frame flag to true so that face_recognition package can use it. Code Snippet:

```
image.setflags(write=True)
```

For Demo Code Have A Look:

```
#import the necessary packages

from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

#initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

#allow the camera to warmup

time.sleep(0.1)

#capture frames from the camera

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text

    image = frame.array
    image.setflags(write=True)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the q key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
         break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```